# How to find a certain coordinate on path relative to another path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am learning AI and SVG animation. I got the [SVG from flaticon](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/pressure_234816). I would like to rotate the pointer around a point and make it look like the gauge is actually working. To achieve this, I need to find the coordinates on the indicator where the bases's midpoint is.

So.:

- I am rotating the pointer
- I know the base's midpoint
- Want to know which (`x`,`y`) is the base's midpoint on the indicator (`x'`, `y'`)

Finding the midpoint on the base is not hard, but how can I translate the coordinate to the pointer? (I will actually need to transform the indicator's coordinate to an `x'` and `y'` percentage afterwards to be able to make it responsive).

I guess I would need to figure out points a lot of times later, so I would like to be able to find such points fast.

Edit: 
I actually want to rotate the pointer in my animation (JavaScript). I can reference the pointer using the path's id, but to apply the transformation, I need a transformation origin. Which I cannot measure.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Illustrator you don't need any coordinate, if we had to do illustrations based on coordinates it would be a madness ;-)

- Select the circle and the pointer
- Prss <kbd>R</kbd> to activate the **Rotation Tool**
- Pres <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> Win to activate the **Outline View**
- Click the circle center once to define the rotation center
- Click the pointer top point and rotate

[image]

To see the coordinates points:

- Pres <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> Win to activate the **Smart guides**
- Put the mouse over the circle center to see `x, y` coordinate numbers

[image]

If you need reference points between two shapes, use the **Measure Tool** (the ruler) and the **Info Panel** to see the coordinates info

[image: Measure Tool]

Comment: Updated my question, I need to `coordiantes` or the `percentages` of the midpoint
Thanks for the tip btw, at least I can align it perfectly now.

Comment: These are coordiantes relative to the whole document not the pointer. Do I need to copy and paste them to a new document, set the document size to match the path and do this?

Comment: Answer updated. I showed you all the possible tools, I think there are no more options inside Illustrator

Comment: Measure tool works, I had to copy the base and the pointer to a new document though, because I had to use the measure tool from the top left corner and the selection outline (rectangle) disappears if I start using the measure tool and the circlepoint too, so I can only measure If I place new objects for help. 
Thanks!